# Как заменить все значения в одном столбце на средние?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть DataFrame. В нем два столбца. В столбце "А" - переменная, в столбце "B" - метка класса.

Как заменить значения в столбце "А" на средние значения по соответствующему классу?

Вычислить сами средние значения несложно:

```
    df.groupby('B')['A'].mean()
```

Но как теперь заменить все значения в столбце "А" на вычисленные средние?

Answer (score 4):

Воспользуйтесь функцией [GroupBy.transform()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation).

Пример:

исходный DF:

```
In [36]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.randint(0, 10, 10), 'B':np.random.choice(list('XYZ'), 10)})

In [37]: df
Out[37]:
   A  B
0  8  Y
1  8  Z
2  3  Z
3  1  Y
4  3  Y
5  5  Z
6  7  Z
7  1  X
8  4  X
9  2  Y
```

Решение:

```
In [39]: df['avg_A'] = df.groupby('B')['A'].transform('mean')
```

Результат:

```
In [40]: df
Out[40]:
   A  B  avg_A
0  8  Y   3.50
1  8  Z   5.75
2  3  Z   5.75
3  1  Y   3.50
4  3  Y   3.50
5  5  Z   5.75
6  7  Z   5.75
7  1  X   2.50
8  4  X   2.50
9  2  Y   3.50
```

если надо заменить значения в колонке `A`:

```
df['A'] = df.groupby('B')['A'].transform('mean')
```